# Trying to access a s3 bucket using boto3, but getting 403

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I wrote a python script to download some files from an s3 bucket. The script works just fine on one machine, but breaks on another. 
Here is the exception I get: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden.

I am pretty sure it's related to some system configurations, or something related to the registry, but don't know what exactly. Both machines are running Windows 7 and python 3.5.
Any suggestions.

Comment: Do you have the was credentials set up correctly?

Comment: Check the **role** that was selected when each instance was launched. It will define the permissions available to applications on the instance. Also, check whether credentials have been provided locally in configuration files on one of the computers.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The credentials are hard coded in the script.  The role shouldn't matter as these files are public anyway.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: The question probably got down-voted because it's not strictly programming-related. If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Answer (score 8):

The issue was actually being caused by the system time being incorrect. I fixed the system time and the problem is fixed.

Comment: oh my god, this is exactly my issue!
how did you figure this out?

Comment: same here, I just execute `sudo -S timedatectl set-ntp true` and everything works

Answer (score 1):

So forbidden means you dont have access to perform the operation. Check you have permission to perform read on that specific bucket and also you have supplied valid IAM keys. Below is the sample policy for getting read and list access to bucket.

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement":[
  {
     "Sid":"statement1",

     "Effect":"Allow",
     "Action":[
        "s3:List*",
        "s3:GetObject"
     ],
     "Resource":[
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
     ]
   }
]
}
```

More info here:

- [Specifying Permissions in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html)
- [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Comment: The '/*' part in the Resource section is essential for accessing any object in the bucket. I spent significant time solving the issue having path without it "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname".